# How to create grouped barplot from dictionary using d3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, bar-chart

I am trying to create a barplot using a dictionary that i created from an existing dataset. It's structure is something like this:

```
dataset = ["2001" : [{month: "January", total : 200}, {month: "February", total : 100}, {month: "July", total : 24}], 
"2002" : [{month: "January", total : 120}, {month: "February", total : 400}, {month: "July", total : 98}],
"2003" : [{month: "January", total : 45}, {month: "February", total : 200}, {month: "July", total : 11}]
```

And, what I'm trying to do is show the years in the x axis, and in the y axis would represent the total value. Each year would also have three bars, one for each month, with it's height being the value of total. This is an image of what I am trying to do, except I'm having difficulty adding the x axis and in the logic to build the bars for each month.

[image]

If somebody could lend me a hand I would be very thankful. Thank you. Code I already have:

```
               //var maximum is max of all total values, I already have code for this
                var years= []
                var subgroups = ["January", "February", "July"]
                for (k in dataset) {
                    groups.push(k);
                 }
                  // set the dimensions and margins of the graph
                  var margin = { top: 10, right: 30, bottom: 20, left: 50 },
                      width = 460 - margin.left - margin.right,
                      height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

                  // append the svg object to the body of the page
                  var svg = d3.select("#Viz_area")
                      .append("svg")
                      .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
                      .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
                      .append("g")
                      .attr("transform",
                          "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
                  // Add X axis
                  var x = d3.scaleBand()
                      .domain(years)
                      .range([0, width])
                      .padding([0.2])
                  svg.append("g")
                      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
                      .call(d3.axisBottom(x).tickSize(0));

                  // Add Y axis
                  var y = d3.scaleLinear()
                      .domain([0, maximum])
                      .range([height, 0]);
                  svg.append("g")
                      .call(d3.axisLeft(y));


                  var color = d3.scaleOrdinal()
                      .domain(subgroups)
                      .range(['#e41a1c','#377eb8','#4daf4a'])
```

```
                  //Part I need help with

                   svg.append("g")
                     .selectAll("g")
                      // Enter in data = loop year per year
                     .data(dataset)
                     .enter()
                     .append("g")
                     .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x(d.group) + ",0)"; })
                     .selectAll("rect")
```

Comment: Can you share your code sample inside a codepen, codesandbox, or https://blockbuilder.org/ pen? It'll be easier to see the gap between where you are and where want to be that way.

Comment: Just to add to @CameronYick comment, he is correct it would be easier with a working example of where you are. But looking at your code and desired output you need to have 2 `x` axis scales. Grouped bar charts have two `scaleBand()`, one for the macrosccopic displacement, i.e. banana, poacee etc and the other for the microscopic displacement i.e. red, green, blue. See this example to understand more: https://observablehq.com/@d3/grouped-bar-chart